# SwiftUI Corner radius of child view changes when superview also gets corner radius

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm having an issue with setting the correct corner radius for a view. Let's say I have a view like this:

```
HStack {
    Text("Hello").padding().background(Color.red).cornerRadius(.infinity)
}
```

Which looks like this: [image: correct result]

As you can see the corners are perfectly round, which is **the desired effect**. 
The problem is, that when I'm adding a corner radius to the superview, in this case the `HStack`, the corner radius of my child view starts to exceed the boundaries that make the corner perfectly round:

```
HStack {     
    Text("Hello").padding().background(Color.red).cornerRadius(.infinity)
}.cornerRadius(16)
```

[image: wrong result]

The question is, how can I make sure that the corner radius of the child view stays perfect like in the first image?

Comment: which is the code of the second image result?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia The same as above but then with a corner radius on the HStack, I've edited the question to show the full example.

Comment: I don't know why you are rounded the HStack with only one element, but maybe if youìll add Space() before and after Text, HStack don't erode the red button

Comment: The example I provided is simplified to focus on the problem. Adding `Spacer()` before and after doesn't work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had to wrap the view in a compositing group to make it work.

Working example here:

```
HStack {
    Text("Hello")
    .padding()
    .background(Color.red)
    .cornerRadius(.infinity)
    .compositingGroup()
}.cornerRadius(16)
```